Examples of decompositions of involutions
The book "Algebra and Geometry" by Beardon introduces Theorem 6.1.4 which states that "Every isometry of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is the composition of at most four reﬂections", and then states:

...in some sense, Theorem 6.1.4 is analogous to the result that a
permutation of a ﬁnite set can be expressed as a product of transpositions. The
common feature of these two results (and other results too) is that a given map
$f$ is being expressed as a composition of simpler maps $f_j$ for which $f^2_j = I $

Beardon mentions "and other results too" but does not mention which results this also applies to. So, what are some examples of other results for types of functions/maps $f$ which can be decomposed as products of involutions, IE maps $f_j$ for which $f^2_j = I $?
